# Google Play's language in English

Tags: google-play

For my masters thesis i need to automatically write the information of different android apps from Google Play into a text file. so im using perl scripting language for this automation. My perl script can write information in that text file which is given in the Google Play website but not in English language. As I am located in Sweden, im getting the Swedish version of those apps information. i tried different ways (by changing the language in setting) to make the default language of Google and Google Chrome in English but still written information are in Swedish version. but my browser and everything is in English. Does anyone can help me in this issue? I cannot use information in Swedish language for further analysis.

thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

How about adding a query string parameter `hl=en`? Google supports it on some of its websites, chances are that Google Play website supports it too.

If I call Google Play website with:

https://play.google.com/store?hl=en

I got english locales. If I call it with

https://play.google.com/store?hl=de

I got German locales etc.

Comment: There is a way to get a specific currency on G Play website?