# Response of Ajax Request not in English

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, web-scraping

Basically i created an online API to scrape data from the Google play store, the API was working fine on my localhost server and everything was according to what I designed but, after uploading the API to my online server, when i send request to scrape data from the Google play store, it returns me in a foreign language, which Google translate says is "INDONESIAN"

So i did some research and modified the headers, currently these are my headers:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Accept-Encoding: gzip');
header('Accept-Language: en');
header('Content-Language: en');
```

All of them are declared in PHP, but nothing happened, response is still in "INDONESIAN". I am getting what i want, just not in the desired language; please answer as quickly as possible

Comment: What if you change `en` to `en-us`

Comment: did that and still the same result, i even tried en-US, but still INDONESIAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in another post completely different than this,

i just had to append the "&hl=en" at the end of the play store link to make it open in english only like

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id='.$appPackageName.'&hl=en
```

[Google Play's language in English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914653/google-plays-language-in-english)